# How to listen firebase real-time changes into Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a real-time chat application using firebase and React js. I create a const functions = require('firebase-functions');
called "**chats**" inside the firebase. This collection contains unique **room_ID**(a combination of sender and receiver) and that document again contains **subcollections** called "messages". Each collection inside the message has infomation like message, time, sender_id, and read status.

Now, every time, when I receive a new message into the chat list I have to update the conversation. I use **componentDidMount()** method of **Reactjs** and write below code:

```
firestore.collection('chats').doc("b7EuhNpdzXUlxhSgDkn2a6oReTl1_OZbrlH8FjmVFqSAtAc0A6TUHS3I3").collection("messages")
.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  console.log("querySnapshot", querySnapshot)
  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    console.log("change", change)
    if (change.type === 'added') {
      this.setState({messages : [...this.state.messages, change.doc.data()]});
      console.log('New city: ', change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === 'modified') {
      console.log('Modified city: ', change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === 'removed') {
      console.log('Removed city: ', change.doc.data());
    }
  });
});
```

You can see here that, It will only work for a single room(b7EuhNpdzXUlxhSgDkn2a6oReTl1_OZbrlH8FjmVFqSAtAc0A6TUHS3I3). I want to write query in such a way that it will listen to the message for each contact. For that, I have to remove the restriction of specific doc.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Here is the structure of Firebase database.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found it a bit confusing to visualize your firebase structure with the way you described it, could you share a screenshot or a tree-like representation of what it looks like? Also, from what I understood, you want to watch every document on your room subcollection for changes, is that correct?

Comment: @ralemos Yes you are right

Comment: ok, so can you share a screenshot or a tree-like representation of what your firestore structure actually looks like so we can help to create a proper listener for it?

Comment: I have added screenshots of my firebase structure.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a few better approaches to fetch the data you want would be to either:

- Restructure your Firestore to have only a `messages` collection, like the following example structure:

  ```
  messages collection
      uid
      receiverUserId
      senderUserId
      msg
      read
      time
  ```

With this approach you could filter the documents you are watching, for example documents received by the currently authenticated user from multiple users, by doing something like this:

```
firestore.collection("messages")
  .where("receiverUserId", "==", authUid)
  .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
     //do whatever
});
```

- Create multiple listeners, one for each `chats` document, to watch it's subsequent `messages` subcollection. So you could do something like this **untested** code:

  ```
  firestore.collection('chats').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var eachChatRef = firestore.collection('chats').doc(doc.documentID)
        var messagesRef = eachChatRef.collection("messages");
        messagesRef.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(messageDoc) {
                // Do whatever
            });
        });
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: sorry, but as I said above - yes, you can - "CollectionGroups", which query all sub-collections of the same name **as if they were a single top-level collection**

Comment: I thought that Collection groups were not applicable on this case for some reason, I will adapt my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the documentation for CollectionGroups - set your listener to the .collectionGroup("messages") - you will have to process through the changes for *all* of the different "chats" documents.  (HINT: each returned messages DocRef includes the refPath field - which you can trivially parse to find the path to the "parent" chat document)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have one more query. Currently, my firebase listener called every time when I reload the page for previously added data. Can I set time constraint on it so I can receive a rela-time update once I reload the page?

Comment: What you are asking for *here* is not a listener - you just want to retrieve documents each time you reload the page.  Nothing at all to do with a listener - a Listener is an *asynchronous* event that sends you the results of a query every time they *change* - so you don't *have* to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

To extend to @LeadDreamer answer, this worked for me to listen to changes in all documents in a collection using `collectionGroup`:

```
const unsub = () =>
  onSnapshot(collectionGroup(db, "reservations"), (doc) => {
    doc.docs.forEach((d) => {
      console.log(d.data());
    });
  });
```